# sidebar navigation that expands from small icons

Tags: bootstrap-4, sidebar

So this is kinda a weird question but canva.com has the coolest sidebar I have ever seen. Its got smile icons that then expand into a bigger selection area. Does anyone have any idea how I would do that in bootstrap 4? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to find this type of `side-bar` on internet easily especially in `Bootstrap`.

`CODEPEN` is the best source where you can find plenty of sidebars and other `code` related stuff's

Here is the [code](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentTabs/index4.html) of somewhat similar to the action you want on each button click of sidebar. you can download it from [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/12/animated-content-tabs-with-css3/). It has various version `demo 4` is similar to your's need

codepen link of [sidebar](https://codepen.io/Samuel87/pen/vYNmoXW)

You can easily reduce the width of the left side `div` content based on your need and add `search bar` and rest of the stuff.

Comment: this isn't exactly what I needed but it pointed me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: How's your search going?  I've been looking for a Canva style sidebar widget as well.